# Sybase TSQL how to select without `-` chars

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase, isql

My question is very simple, I am trying to print a combination of text and numbers, by using the `SELECT` statement. However, when I try to print text using this method, I get a lot of miscellaneous `-` chars.

How can I use the select statement without having it print the `-` chars?

For example:

`SELECT "HELLO WORLD"`

Would result in:

```
---------------------
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: `SELECT` does not print things...  Are you talking about output in some sort of client program?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise, No, if I were to just run the stored procedure from a shell script. The `SELECT` statements that I use to print numbers and text will also produce `----------`

Comment: I'm assuming you are running *isql* against ASE, but if that's not the case, then let us know what client program you are running, and what Sybase database product/version you are running.

Comment: @MichaelGardner, Hi Michael I am mistaken, but now that you have mentioned `isql`, yes I am using `isql`. How can I remove the `-` chars with `isql`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When lauching *isql* use the *-b* option to suppress header printing.

```
isql -Uusername -Sservername -b
```